# Wrong dynamic library loading when using absolute FilePath

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries

I have the following Code that writes two times into a cpp file and then compiles the cpp file and executes the resulting shared libs: (on macOS)

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QLibrary>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QFileInfo>

void compileAndExecute(QFileInfo source, QString libName){
    QString libPath = source.absolutePath()+"/"+libName + ".so";
    QString rename = "test.so";
    QProcess p;
    //QString cmd = "g++ -shared -fPIC -std=c++14 -O3 " + source.absoluteFilePath() + " -o " + QFileInfo(rename).absoluteFilePath() + " ";
    QString cmd = "g++ -shared -fPIC -std=c++14 -O3 " + source.absoluteFilePath() + " -o " + rename + " ";
    qDebug() << cmd;
    p.start("bash", QStringList() << "-c" << cmd);
    p.waitForFinished();
    qDebug().noquote() <<"ERR : "<< QString(p.readAllStandardError());
    qDebug().noquote() <<"OuT : "<< QString(p.readAllStandardError());
    if(p.exitCode() != 0){
        qDebug() << p.errorString();
        qDebug() << p.error();
    }else{
        if(p.exitCode()==0){
            QFile::rename(rename,libPath );
            QLibrary lib(libPath);
            if(lib.load()){
                auto f = lib.resolve("print");
                if(f)
                    f();
                else
                    qDebug() << "Error, Function is null";
            }else{
                qDebug() << "Error loading lib";
            }
        }
    }
}

QFileInfo generateCode(int numberPrinted, QString filename){
    QFile file( filename );
    Q_ASSERT( file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) );

    QTextStream stream( &file );
    stream << "#include <iostream>" << endl;
    stream << "extern \"C\" { " << endl;
    stream << " void print(){" << endl
           << "     std::cout << " + QString::number(numberPrinted) + " << std::endl;" << endl
           << " }" << endl;
    stream << "}" << endl;
    stream.flush();
    file.close();
    return file;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    compileAndExecute(generateCode(1,"Source.cpp"),"lib1");
    compileAndExecute(generateCode(2,"Source.cpp"),"lib2");
    QFile::remove("Source.cpp");
    QFile::remove("lib1.so");
    QFile::remove("lib2.so");
    return 0;
}
```

when i execute it, I get the right result:

```
1
2
```

But when I change line 4 in the compileAndExecute function from `" -o " + rename` to `" -o " + QFileInfo(rename).absoluteFilePath()` I get the Output

```
1
1
```

The second lib will not load correctly. The resolve function will return the exact same address for the function pointer.

Can somebody explain this behavior?

Comment: In arch linux I do not have that behavior, it works correctly, what is the output of `qDebug() << rename;` and `qDebug() << QFileInfo(rename).absoluteFilePath()`?

Comment: The output is the following: (my user name contains no spaces)

    `"test.so"`
    `"/Users/<myUserName>/build-VerifyBug-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_clang_64bit2-Debug/test.so"`

Comment: In what folder is your executable?

Comment: Working in win 7 !!! both output same results.

Comment: In the same folder where the shared libs are. `/Users/<myUserName>/build-VerifyBug-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_clang_64bit2-Debug/`